# Java method doesnt execute from Javascript using Freemarker

Tags: javascript, java, freemarker

I am trying to execute Java method in Javascript over object which I get from Java code using Freemarker. 
I have java object "actual_id" of type "Settinga" and method "setActual_id" which just sets one attribute of the object. This is my call of the method in js:

```
var idd = ${actual_id}.setActual_id(variable);
```

Instead of execution in html code I see:

```
javaclassurl$Settinga@5beccfce.setActual_id(variable);
```

And there is error: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Why it doesnt execute?
Following call is executed as expected but I need to include variable:

```
var idd = "${actual_id.setActual_id("aaa01dd3-abe4-4d50-a69e-62b04199b7c5")}";
```

I understand that Freemarker expressions are translated during page generation and when I use just string its easily interpreted and can be executed but during page generation my variable which I want to include in the call isnt known so need to make execution somehow else...

Answer (score 0):

Because the way it works is this: FreeMarker is executed on the server, resolving all the `${...}` to mere text, then the browser on the client side gets the resulting HTML and executes the JavaScript.